# Sent item has changed font to Times New Roman. Default font is Calibri 11

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2013

We use Outlook 2010 / 2013. We have two exchange accounts. One local (domain) and one Office 365.

If we send internal mail, fonts are 100%.

If we reply to an external email sometimes it is 100% but other times our font has been changed to Times Roman.

All obvious settings have been looked at, in Outlook, Internet options, the defaults templates for email (.dotm) etc.

I am looking for a global solution and not one that involves changes to each machine on the network.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones that have been "changed to Times", check the format the mail is being sent as.

If it's sending as **Plain-text** then any custom fonts will be removed, and Outlook usually defaults to Times New Roman to display plain-text.

The response type (Plain-text, vs. Rich-text (RTF) vs. HTML) is set globally, but can be overridden by settings in the individual Outlook contacts, and that can be further overridden per-email response, depending on the format type of the email you're replying to (if you reply to a plain-text email, Outlook may/will automatically assume Plain-text for the response).

More info on checking/setting that setting per-contact is available [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2371-outlook-contact-always-send-plain-text.html) (amongst other places).

Comment: I would check this too, but to clarify - The plain text option is not changing the font in the body of the E-Mail, it's removing the font information altogether. Outlook might **display** the text in Times New Roman.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me as well for Outlook 2010. To fix this, I went into "Stationery and Fonts", changed the fonts to something else, then re-saved the font settings back to what I wanted (Arial as default), then closed and re-opened Outlook again and it's normal again.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue and this is what worked for me.

Our users are running office 2016 and all the default fonts are set to calibri 11pt regular font. But when 1 user would send an email it would revert back to times new roman and send the email in that font.

Our version of office had been activated but it seems like for some reason it did not take effect. I went to "change product key" and re entered our license which then prompted to activate online. After doing that and getting a notice that our version of office was activated all of my changes stayed in place.

Seems like when you activate office there is a potential error if it doesn't finishing activating which may cause your changes to revert since you aren't running a "full" version of office 2016.

hope that helps -good luck